# Time calculation for task reports

Tags: environments, parsing

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{dayreport}{\begin{tabular}{ll}\hline Task & Time\\\hline}{\hline\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\task}[2]{#1 & #2\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{dayreport}
\task{a}{1 hr\hphantom{s}}
\task{b}{2 hrs}
\task{c}{1 hr 30 mins}
\end{dayreport}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Tasks]

I would like to automate some tasks like inputing time and calculating total times. Time inputing examples:

- `\task{a}{1}` would produce `a & 1 hr\hphantom{s}`
- `\task{a}{1:30}` would produce `a & 1 hr 30 mins`
- `\task{a}{2}` would produce `a & 2 hrs`

Total time calculation:

```
\begin{dayreport}
\task{a}{1}
\task{a}{1:30}
\task{a}{2}
\begin{endreport}
```

would produce `Total time: & 4 hrs 30 mins \\` when ending `dayreport`.

Is something like that possible in LaTeX (I would probably need string splitting, simple arithmetic and if-then-else constructs)? Should I rather write a short program to parse the input and output the appropriate LaTeX code?

Comment: have a look: https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/f4bcca6281a6742e/3b79cc8ec2ec09c6?lnk=gst&hl=de

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\def\task#1{\@task#1::\@nil}
\def\@task#1:#2:#3\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    % no minutes
    #1 hr\ifnum#1=\@ne\hphantom{s}\else s\fi
  \else
    #1 hr\ifnum#1=\@ne\else s\fi
    \ #2 mins
  \fi}
\makeatother
...
\task{1}

\task{1:30}

\task{2:54}
```

[image: Result]

The problem is to parse the result. After `\task{1}` the token list is

```
\@task 1::\@nil
```

so that `#1` is `1`, while `#2` and `#3` are empty (the arguments to `\@task` are delimited by semicolons and by `\@nil`). After `\task{1:30}` we get

```
\@task 1:30::\@nil
```

so `#1` is `1`, `#2` is `30` and `#3` is `:`. The rest is just following the conditional: `\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax` is true when `#2` is empty. It's just a matter to add some `\def` in the branches of the conditional if one wants to store the time for calculations.

Answer (score 4):

Putting together the advice given by egreg on questions [Converting command to result](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20185/converting-command-to-result), [Storing environment arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20132/storing-environment-arguments), [What are the exact semantics of \detokenize?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20059/what-detokenize-command-does) as well as this one, I managed to create what I wanted.

For the sake of completeness, I am providing the code. There are still some rough edges: `task{0:15}` will print `0 hrs 15 mins`, the tables don't take up the whole `\textwidth`, etc. As a proof of concept, I am very satisfied.

#### report.tex

```
\documentclass{workreport}

\begin{document}
\begin{dayreport}{June 13, 2011}
\task{First task}{3}
\task{Second task}{1:12}
\task{Third task}{3:15}
\end{dayreport}

\begin{dayreport}{June 14, 2011}
\task{Fourth task}{1:15}
\task{Fifth task}{2}
\task{Sixth task}{1}
\end{dayreport}

\totaltime

\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: Task report]

#### workreport.cls

```
% workreport.cls
\ProvidesClass{workreport}
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

% infix arithmetic
\usepackage{calc}

% setting section titles
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[]

% nicer looking table rules
\usepackage{booktabs}

% counters for time calculation
\newcounter{totaltime}
\setcounter{totaltime}{0}
\newcounter{dailytime}
\setcounter{dailytime}{0}
\newcounter{hours}
\setcounter{hours}{0}
\newcounter{minutes}
\setcounter{minutes}{0}

% required for xappto command
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\totaltimerows}{}
\newcommand{\totaltime}{
\section*{Total Work Hours}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.75\textwidth}r}
\toprule
Day     &   Work hours \\
\midrule
\totaltimerows
\bottomrule
\setcounter{minutes}{\thetotaltime-((\thetotaltime/60)*60)}
\setcounter{hours}{\thetotaltime/60}
\emph{Total work hours:} & \displaytime{\thehours:\theminutes}\\
\end{tabular}
}

% prints time and advances time counters, format is \tasktime{hh:mm}
\def\tasktime#1{\@tasktime#1::\@nil}
\def\@tasktime#1:#2:#3\@nil{%
    % add hours time to counter
    \setcounter{dailytime}{\thedailytime+#1*60}
    % if there are no minutes, detokenize is empty so \relax=\relax
    % output hour/hours 
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
        #1 hr\ifnum#1=\@ne\hphantom{s}\else s\fi
    \else
        % check if minutes are greater than 0
        \ifnum#2>0
            % add minutes to counter and output time
            \setcounter{dailytime}{\thedailytime+#2}
            #1 hr%
                \ifnum#1=\@ne
                % '\' is for spacing
                \else s\fi \ #2 mins
        % if the minutes are not greater than 0
        \else
            #1 hr\ifnum#1=\@ne\hphantom{s}\else s\fi
    \fi
    \fi}

% prints time but does not advance the time counters
\def\displaytime#1{\@displaytime#1::\@nil}
\def\@displaytime#1:#2:#3\@nil{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
        #1 hr\ifnum#1=\@ne\hphantom{s}\else s\fi
    \else
        \ifnum#2>0
            #1 hr%
                \ifnum#1=\@ne
                \else s\fi \ #2 mins
        \else
            #1 hr\ifnum#1=\@ne\hphantom{s}\else s\fi
    \fi
    \fi}

\newcommand{\task}[2]{#1 & \tasktime{#2}\\}

\newenvironment{dayreport}[1]{%
    \section*{#1}
    \appto\totaltimerows{#1 & }
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.75\textwidth}r}
    \toprule
    Task                    &   Approximate time \\
    \midrule}{
    \bottomrule
    \setcounter{minutes}{\thedailytime-((\thedailytime/60)*60)}
    \setcounter{hours}{\thedailytime/60}
    \setcounter{totaltime}{\thetotaltime+\thedailytime}%
    \setcounter{dailytime}{0}%
    \emph{Total time:}  &   \displaytime{\thehours:\theminutes}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \xappto\totaltimerows{\displaytime{\thehours:\theminutes}\noexpand\\}   
}
```

Comment: That is a very helpful piece of code.