# What are the exact semantics of \detokenize?

Tags: tex-core, primitives, detokenize

How does `\detokenize` work?

The e-TeX Short Reference Manual states:

> When followed by a `<general text>`,
>   expands to yield a sequence of
>   character tokens of `\catcode` 10
>   (space) or 12 (other) corresponding to
>   a decomposition of the tokens of the
>   `<balanced text>` of the unexpanded
>   `<general text>`; c.f. `\showtokens`.
>   The effect is rather as if
>   `\scantokens` applied to the `<general
>   text>` within a régime in which only
>   `\catcodes` 10 and 12 existed. Note
>   that in order to preserve the
>   boundaries between control words and
>   any following letter, a space is
>   yielded after each control word
>   including the last.

What does that mean in plain English? I want to understand this snippet of code:

```
\def\task#1{\@task#1::\@nil}
\def\@task#1:#2:#3\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
  ...
```

I think that `\task` is defined as a macro taking one argument which calls `\@task`. I don't know what `\@nil` means -- it is probably used to end the macro call. I also don't know what `\relax` and `\detokenize` do, but detokenize takes the second part of the argument for the `task macro` (the parts are separated with semicolons).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`\task` takes one argument, passing it to `\@task` which is defined in such a way that its arguments are *delimited*; if the call is

```
\@task xyz:AB:cde:u\@nil
```

the first argument is `xyz`, the second is `AB` and the third is `cde:u`. Here `\@nil` doesn't mean anything, it's just required by the syntax of `\@task` and TeX throws it away.

`\relax` is a primitive of TeX, its function is "do nothing". The test

```
\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
```

is a safe way to determine if the argument `#2` is empty. If it is, `\detokenize{#2}` expands to nothing, so `\if` compares the tokens `\relax` and `\relax`, which are indeed equal, so the "true" branch is followed, which starts immediately after the second `\relax`, up to and excluding `\else`. If `#2` is not empty, say it's `30`, `\if` will compare `\relax` with `3` which are different, so the "false" branch is followed, which starts after `\else` up to and excluding `\fi`.[1]

The similar construct `\if\relax#2\relax` does not work in all cases, because "all control sequences are equal as far as \if is concerned" [2]. It would not work if `#2` was `\relax` (or any other control sequence, possibly followed by other tokens)! So we use `\detokenize` that, as explained also by Joseph, splits everything into a string. So, even in the weird case that `#2` is `\relax`, `\if` would compare the token `\relax` with the *character* `\`, which are different.

---

[1] This is not strictly true, but it's an approximation of the truth sufficient for the purpose of this description.

[2] TeX by Topic (section 13.2.1)

Comment: Thank you again! I think that I understand it now. There are two more points that are not that clear to me:
1. Why are arguments for `\@task` split like that? `xyz`+`AB`+`cde` or `xyz`+`AB:cde`+`u` or `xyz`+`AB`+`cde:u` all seem to satisfy <part>:<part>:<part>.
2. Will `\detokenize` split `\relax` into `\ ` `r` `e` `l` `a` `x`?

Comment: @ipavlic 1. TeX takes always the *shortest* token list that satisfies the requests (as long as the braces are balanced) so the first argument is anything up to the first colon, the second is anything from the first to the second colon and the third is anything from the second colon to `\@nil`. 2. Yes.

Comment: Doesn't then the third argument has to be `cde:u` instead of `u` as written in the answer? This should not be nitpicking, I am really not sure enough to edit it. If I am wrong, please explain why.

Comment: @MMM You're right.

Answer (score 30):

The `\detokenize` primitive converts all of its input into category code 12 ('other') tokens, except for spaces which stay as category code 10 ('space'). It is used to convert tokens into strings. For example, if we have

```
\detokenize{\foo}
```

then `\foo` would be a control word, *i.e.* one token, which is converted into 5 string characters (`\`, `f`, `o`, `o`, ), all which are 'other' characters other than the space, which is a 'space'. Note the additional space at the end here: `\detokenize` adds a space after each 'control word' (see below).

I'll take your example one step at a time. First, `\@nil` is being used as a delimiter here. The definition of `\@task` means that the argument must contain `:`, then `:` again and finally `\@nil`. This is used to 'tidy up' awkward input

```
\task{stuff:more stuff}
```

will be turned into

```
 \@task stuff:more stuff::\@nil
```

which means `#1` is `stuff`, `#2` is `more stuff` and `#3` is `:`. Thus it ensures that everything is 'used up': this is a common requirement.

---

To see `\detokenize` in action, try something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\edef\test{\detokenize{\test}}
\show\test
\begin{document}
\detokenize{\test}
\end{document}
```

---

A bit more on the addition of spaces by `\detokenize`, and indeed more generally. Whenever TeX writes something that can be one or more tokens as a 'string', it always inserts a space after each 'control word' (escape character followed by one or more 'letters') to avoid confusion. For example, with

```
\catcode`\X=12 % 'Other'
\def\foo{\barX}
\meaning\foo
```

you get

```
macro:-> \bar X
```

where the space is not there in the original but tells us that `\bar` is a control sequence followed by `X`, rather than printing just `\barX`, which looks like it's a different thing. This makes sense as TeX skips spaces after control words, so the two versions are equivalent as far as it is concerned.

This 'insert spaces' behaviour is respected by `\detokenize`, meaning that you get a space after each control word. The only place TeX doesn't insert these spaces is with `\string`, which can only be used on a single token and so in places where there is no possible 'confusion'.

Comment: Let me see if I understand it correctly. `#1` from `task` expands to `stuff:more stuff` in the command `\@task stuff:more stuff::\@nil`. The purpose of the added `::` is to enable input without semicolons, e.g. `\task{1}`. Now the semicolons will be concatenated to `1` to form `1::` which will satisfy the two-semicolons requirement of `\@task`.

Comment: @ipavlic: `#1` is never expanded, rather it is *replaced* by the input, but the result is as you say `\@task stuff:more stuff::\@nil` is executed. You are also right about the `::` part - without this, you'd be in trouble with non-conforming input.

Comment: @ipavlic: `\detokenize` leaves the result in the input stream. Thus you end up with `\detokenize{foo}` => `foo` wherever it was used. In the current case, this is as part of a test, which will throw away any excess tokens. On the other hand, if you use it in a typesetting context then the material will just be typeset. See my edit

Comment: @Joseph: I guess that the word expand has a special meaning in LaTeX, so "replace" would be more fitting. If I understand correctly, depending on the context, the commands behave a bit differently -- sometimes the parts of the content are replaced, and sometimes they are typeset "as they are". I think I am beginning to understand the concept of how LaTeX works. Thank you!

Comment: @ipavlic: This is all TeX, not LaTeX *per se*. Expansion has a very precise meaning in TeX programming, and for low-level TeX questions like this one I think it's important to be careful about the terminology.

Comment: @ipavlic: On the insertion of tokens, this always happens in the same way, but what TeX then does with the tokens depends on the situation. So the resulting tokens are typeset in a 'typesetting context'.

Comment: @Joseph: I agree with you on the importance of using proper terminology.

Comment: So why does `\detokenize{\something}\bye` comes out as '"something' in the typeset output? I'd expect '\something'.

Comment: @AlexG Font issue: the OT1 (Knuth original) font encoding doesn't have a ``\`` in the appropriate slot, it has `"`. Assuming LaTeX, using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` will solve this as in T1 encoding the slot is correct.

Comment: Thanks!!! And what is the difference between `\detokenize` and `\string` (apart from `\string` only working on a single token that follows)? They seem to fulfil a similar task.

Comment: @AlexG Well the difference in number of tokens is pretty significant! `\detokenize` works in the same way as say `\meaning` or writing to a toks to file: spaces are inserted by TeX after each control word. On the other hand, `string` does not do this. Try for example `\detokenize{\foo\bar\baz}` and `\string\foo\string\bar\string\baz` to see this. The two primitives are both useful.

Comment: Thanks again! But why was `\detokenize` designed in this way? This gives rise to new [problems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44391).

Comment: @AlexG You'd have to ask the NTS team for a definitive answer, but if you read the docs it's clear that `\detokenize` and `\unexpanded` are supposed to provide expandable access to things that otherwise require assignments. The way they are described, they are supposed to work the same as going _via_ a toks, and if you do that the TeX behaviour is to add spaces. The point of that is with multiple tokens, something like ``\catcode`\a=12\detokenize{\fooa}`` would leave `\fooa` (looks like one control word), rather than `\foo a` (one control word and one token).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and for your extended answer! It makes things clearer now.