# Detokenizing without extra spaces?

Tags: tex-core, expansion

I have a need to pass through potentially arbitrary characters untouched and found this macro:

```
\makeatletter
\def\test#1{\expandafter\zap@space\detokenize{#1} \@empty}
\makeatother
```

The problem is that `\detokenize` inserts spaces after commands in the expansion so I get rid of these with LaTeX's `\zap@space`. Unfortunately, I need to keep any spaces which `\detokenize` did not produce. I suspect that there is some cunning way to do this by redefining the catcode of the space character but it is somewhat beyond me.

For example (yes, it's regular expressions I need to pass through ...),

```
\test{\A\d{2,}.+\z}
```

Should expand to `\A\d{2,}.+\z`

but

```
\test{A test}
```

should expand to `A test` and not lose the space that was there originally.

I should say, that `\verb` doesn't work as these regexp strings are the value of a keyval pair:

```
\macro[key=\test{#1}]
```

**Update** It seems too hard to do this in general without making other things rather messy so I've settled for requiring that any regexps used are canonicalised to use no literal spaces in them. It's always possible to replace them with '\x20' for example in anyway so this means that `\zap@space` will only be zapping spaces created by `\detokenize`, which is fine. Many thanks for all of the answers though as they are very instructive.

Comment: You should add more details about what you need; if it is only about printing, then `\verb|\A\d{2,}.+\z|` would be sufficient.

Comment: You're right, I have added a bit more context.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this. You would need to scan for the backslash followed by characters and only then remove the space -- possible but not trivial. Maybe if you code your `\test` macro in a way that allows to declare the regexes before using them? `\declareregex\myregex{\A\d{2,}.+\z}` (which reads the argument verbatim) and then `\macro[key=\test{\myregex}]`

Comment: I can search out an old solution I made sometime back, but before then let us know if you need to **retokenize** the outcome of detokenizing.

Comment: No, I don't need to retokenize. The raw characters are going elsewhere, not TeX.

Comment: Why go elsewhere? You can use regexes in TeX (the package `l3regex` provides that... of course, it is pretty slow).

Comment: Ah, I don't actually need the regexeps in TeX, I just need to write them elsewhere (XML in fact) without mangling them

Comment: Then why is verbatim not what you need?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is impossible to distinguish `\A .` from `\A.` once TeX has converted those into tokens: the only solution if you need to preserve those spaces is to read the argument verbatim.

However, if you are fine with that, then the simplest method is to update the *l3kernel* and *l3experimental* bundles (and *l3packages*) to a *very* recent version (Februrary 2012), then use tools from the *l3regex* package to add `\string` in front of each token in the argument, and expand. The code below does that (replace `\tl_show:N` by whatever you want to do to the string).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \test #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { . } { \c{string} \0 } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
    % now \l_tmpb_tl contains what you want:
    \tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \test{\A\d{2,}.+ Hello, world!\z}
\end{document}
```

How does it work? `\regex_replace_all:nnN` performs a replacement on a stored token list, so we need to store the argument.

```
\tl_set:Nn    % Set locally
  \l_tmpa_tl  % the "local temporary token list" `\l_tmpa_tl`
  {#1}        % to contain "#1" (the argument).
\regex_replace_all:nnN % Replace every occurrence of
  { . }                % any token, even braces etc.
  {                    % by
    \c{string}         %   \string
    \0                 %   what was matched (the token)
  } \l_tmpa_tl         % in \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_set:Nx        % Set locally, with expansion,
  \l_tmpb_tl      % the "local temporary token list b"
  { \l_tmpa_tl }  % to (the expansion of) `\l_tmpa_tl`
\tl_show:N    % Show the contents of
  \l_tmpb_tl  % the token list variable `\l_tmpb_tl`
```

Of course, under the hood, `l3regex` does a lot of work so it will depend on how many such regular expressions you have to go through.

EDIT: A plain TeX solution for the very specific task your are asking for. I am assuming that the strings never contain the character `^^A` (char code 1). The idea is to use `\lowercase` to change all *true* space tokens to some recognizable character. Then `\detokenize`, and loop through the result one character at a time (this automatically skips spaces) replacing `^^A` by a space.

```
\catcode64=11
\long\def\test#1%
  {%
    \begingroup
      % Ensure that every character is preserved by \lowercase.
      \count@\z@
      \loop\ifnum\count@<256
        \lccode\count@\z@
        \advance\count@\@ne
      \repeat
      % Except spaces, changed to ^^A
      \lccode32=\@ne
      \lowercase
        {%
          \endgroup
          \edef\result{\expandafter\test@\detokenize{#1}\relax}%
        }%
  }
% Then map {^^A => space, space =>} onto the string.
\def\test@#1%
  {%
    \ifx#1\relax\test@end\fi
    \ifnum`#1=\@ne\space\else#1\fi
    \test@
  }
\def\test@end\fi#1\test@{\fi}
\catcode64=12
\test{ab c\d e{f} \fg }\show\result
```

Comment: Bruno: I get `c{string}\c{string}Ac{string} c{string} ...` Please what does it mean?

Comment: @AhmedMusa Update your system.

Comment: @Bruno I used MiKTeX Package Manager less than 2 weeks ago. Which packages do I need to update?

Comment: @AhmedMusa What version is your `l3regex.sty`? Mine is `l3regex.dtx 3326 2012-02-07`

Comment: @AhmedMusa Since your version is too old, `\c` was not implemented yet, and is simpley intepreted as a `c`, so instead of `\string`, you get `c{string}`. This feature is very recent, may less than two weeks. I can check more carefully if you need.

Comment: This is interesting but I'm not sure I can require the use of (very recent) l3* packages in this project. If there is any way to do this in pure TeX do you think?

Comment: @PLK I edited my answer.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Very clever.

Comment: Yes, very clever - I thought it would be "something" like this but it would have taken me weeks to work it out, if at all ... however, I can't seem to splice this anywhere in my .sty without it throwing errors (different errors depending on where I put it). Looks like the catcode macros interfere with something. Is there something obvious to consider here before I start debugging?

Comment: @PLK: just remove the `\catcode` macros. They're setting the catcode of `@` (ascii character 64), similar to LaTeX's `\makeatletter`.

Comment: I thought that but then I get Undefined control sequence for \result?

Comment: @Bruno `\test{ab c\d e{f} \fg }` gives `ab c\de{f} \fg`. Spaces after controls disappear, giving the impression of new control sequences. Eg, `\d` becomes `\de` and `\fg<space>` becomes `\fg`.

Comment: @AhmedMusa Of course: once TeX has tokenized the argument those spaces are lost. That's the meaning of my first paragraph. The only correct solution is to read the argument verbatim. --- PLK, I don't see any way this could happen since in my code the only thing I do to `\result` is to define it. Try changing `\result` to some other name??

Comment: For some reason, whatever I use as the \edef macro name, it always says it is undefined. This also seems to leave the results in this macro rather than just expanding \test to the result?

Comment: @PLK: Neither solution is expandable: `\edef\foo{\test{...}}` will fail. Instead, you can use `\test{...}`, then manipulate the `\result`. In principle, it is possible to provide an expandable solution, but much harder. Also, you might want to add `\protected` in front of `\long\def` in the plain eTeX solution.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the question being tagged as `tex-core` I would like to point at `xparse`. It has the argument specification `v` that does the detokinization without spaces as far as I understand it. Form the manual:

> Arguments of type “v” are read in verbatim mode, which will result in
>   the grabbed argument consisting of tokens of category code 12
>   (“other”), except spaces, which are given category code 10 (“space”).

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\ttfamily #1}
```

And using it with

```
\foo!\A\d{2,}.+\z!
```

produces the same output as

```
\verb!\A\d{2,}.+\z!
```

There are no extra spaces introduced by `xparse`. In this sense the contents of argument `#1` is “untouched”.

Comment: The point is that the OP wants to use this as an argument to another command, which is not possible for this kind of commands.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't really know about xparse. The big problem is that I really need this as a value of a keyval pair and this rules out anything verbatim-like. It's a really quite hard problem. I think I'll have to settle for not allowing spaces in the input and using `\detokenize`

Answer (score 2):

A truly general solution seems difficult but here is my attempt.

Call `\spaceparse` with the argument to be detokenized and parsed for spaces after commands. The result of the parsing is available in the macro `\result`. You would need to call `\result` to see the outcome.

Because `\detokenize` doubles the hash character, we first reverse that action. If you don't require this default action, then use the star (*) form of `\spaceparse`.

You can copy this into a package and call the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
% No conflict with etoolbox.sty:
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\robust@def*\spaceparse{\cpt@testst\sp@ceparse}
\robust@def*\sp@ceparse#1{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\@tempa{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \ifboolTF{cpt@st}{}{\s@expandarg\cpt@pophash\@tempa\@tempa}%
  \edef\@tempa##1{##1\expandcsonce\@tempa\@space\cpt@nil}%
  \edef\@tempb##1{\def##1####1\@space####2\cpt@nil}%
  \@tempb\@tempb{%
    \ifblankTF{##2}{%
      \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@##1}%
    }{%
      \countbackslash{##1}%
      \ifnum\nr=\@ne
        \xifinsetTF{\@car##2\relax\@nil}\cpt@oth@rchars{%
          \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@##1}%
        }{%
          \cptexpanded{\toks@{\the\toks@\unexpanded{##1}\@space}}%
        }%
      \else
        \cptexpanded{\toks@{\the\toks@\unexpanded{##1}\@space}}%
      \fi
      \@tempb##2\cpt@nil
    }%
  }%
  \@tempa{\toks@{}\@tempb}%
  \edef\result{\the\toks@}%
  \postgroupdef\result\endgroup
}
\robust@def*\countbackslash#1{%
  \begingroup
  \@tempcnta\z@
  \def\@tempa##1{%
    \def\@tempa####1##1####2\@nil{%
      \ifblankTF{####2}{}{%
        \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
        \@tempa####2\@nil
      }%
    }%
    \@tempa#1##1\@nil
  }%
  \s@expandarg\@tempa\@backslashchar
  \cptexpanded{\endgroup\def\noexpand\nr{\the\@tempcnta}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Tests:

```
\def\x{##1\A\d{2,}.+\z A B\\x y}
% Content of \x is already read:
\expandafter\spaceparse\expandafter{\x}
\show\result

\spaceparse{xx\x{f} \fg x}
\show\result

\spaceparse{ab c\d e{f} \fg x}
\show\result

\spaceparse{#1\A\d{2,}.+\z A B}
\show\result

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will try this and report back, thanks. I may have to try to see how to convert it to use etoolbox instead of ltxtools though.

Comment: *ltxtools-base* is available on CTAN but, if you want, I can remove the dependence on *ltxtools-base*. However, the solution will have to be longer.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you have put into this already ... unfortunately I can't really use ltxtools as it conflicts with definitions in etoolbox which is a non-negotiable dependency ...

Comment: @PLK I have replaced *ltxtools-base* with *catoptions* and confirmed that there is no command name clash with *etoolbox*. BTW, thanks for highlighting a command name clash between *ltxtools-base* and *etoolbox*.

Comment: Does this work with Lualatex? It seems to require pdflatex?

Answer (score 2):

Expandable answer: `\test` below is defined in such a way that it can be used in any context: `\edef\foo{\test{...}}` works, and similarly `\typeout{\test{...}}`. This relies on undocumented experimental internal features of LaTeX3, and I only guarantee that it works with today's version of `expl3` (it should work with versions from January 8th 2012 until...?).

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \test
  { \tl_act:NNNnn \test_normal:nN \test_group:nn \test_space:n { } }
\cs_new:Npn \test_space:n #1 { \tl_act_output:n {~} }
\cs_new:Npn \test_normal:nN #1 #2
  { \exp_args:No \tl_act_output:n { \token_to_str:N #2 } }
\cs_new:Npx \test_group:nn #1 #2
  {
    \exp_not:N \exp_args:Nf \exp_not:N \tl_act_output:n
      { \exp_not:N \test { \iow_char:N \{ #2 \iow_char:N \} } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\typeout{\test{\a b c}}
\typeout{\test{\d*?z{2,} ??\b\p{Lu}}}
\stop
```

All the magic recursion through brace groups, and finding spaces, is done by `\tl_act:NNNnn`. Don't ask.

Comment: This seems to loose the space after `\a`, giving `\ab` in the log. However, it doesn't if you replace the `\a` with `\!` (or any other non-letter case).

Comment: @Joseph: see comments on my non-expandable answer and Ahmed's comments. Once TeX has tokenized, this space is lost for good; same thing for multiple spaces in a row. The only correct solution is to use verbatim.

Comment: Many thanks for working so hard on this. I think what I may need to do is to try to change the LaTeX interface so that I can use verbatim ... I will see