# Print small TeX code verbatim and render it

Tags: macros, verbatim

To write some documentation, I would like the ability to define a command such as

```
\showcase{x^{y}\in\Omega}
```

which expands to something roughly equivalent to

```
\verb|x^{y}\in\Omega| & $x^{y}\in\Omega$ \\
```

so that I can show what the latex code looks like and how does it show on the document.

Now I now that it isn't really possible to use `\verb` for this because it's **really** fragile and you can't pass arguments from a macro to it. But, assuming that I'm not trying to write anything crazy in the argument to `\showcase` (e.g. braces are always balanced, I don't care much if spaces are collapsed, no `%`'s inside), is there a way to define such a command?

### Update

`\detokenize` does (almost) exactly what I want. Take the following example

```
\newcommand\showcase[1]{{\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}} & $#1$}
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
\showcase{x^{y}}      & \showcase{\hat{x}, \bar{x}} \\
\showcase{x_{y}}      & \showcase{f\colon X \to Y} \\
\showcase{x'}         & \showcase{\sqrt{x+2}} \\
\showcase{x''_{2}}    & \showcase{2 < x \leq 4} \\
\showcase{A^{1}_{2}}  & \showcase{\frac{a+b}{c+d}} \\
\showcase{3\pi/4}     & \showcase{\int_{0}^{1} x^{2} \,dx} \\
\showcase{x\in\Omega} & \showcase{A \cup B \subseteq C \cap D}
\end{tabular}
```

Which produces the output:

[image]

My minor quibbles are that:

- The double `''` seems to have been collapsed into a `"`
- I find mildly annoying the spaces after control sequences. I know why they are there, but could there be a way to remove the space if it is *not* followed by a letter or number? (Or, conversely, if followed by `{` or `_`)

Comment: `\detokenize` might work for you, if you don't have `%` or unbalanced expressions in the verbatim material.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19295/side-by-side-source-and-output-when-documenting-a-style-file (see also the linked questions)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Correct me if I'm wrong but, looking at those packages, they seem to provide example “environments”, I'm looking more for some small almost “inline” code usage (e.g. to make a table). / I'm looking at detokenize now, it (almost!) works, but it has some small problems, will update my question soon.

Comment: No, you're probably right, I haven't looked much at them myself.

Comment: For the spaces/detokenize stuff, see [Detokenizing without extra spaces?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44391/detokenizing-without-extra-spaces). On the `''` business, this is because of the font ligature. You probably want to look `\@noligs` from the LaTeX kernel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For math mode this should work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\showcase}{v}
 {
  \texttt{#1} & \tl_rescan:nn { } { $#1$ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
\showcase{x^{y}}      & \showcase{\hat{x}, \bar{x}} \\
\showcase{x_{y}}      & \showcase{f\colon X \to Y} \\
\showcase{x'}         & \showcase{\sqrt{x+2}} \\
\showcase{x''_{2}}    & \showcase{2 < x \leq 4} \\
\showcase{A^{1}_{2}}  & \showcase{\frac{a+b}{c+d}} \\
\showcase{3\pi/4}     & \showcase{\int_{0}^{1} x^{2} \,dx} \\
\showcase{x\in\Omega} & \showcase{A \cup B \subseteq C \cap D}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Should you want to swap the columns, so the result appears before the code, just change the definition of `\showcase` inverting the cells:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\showcase}{v}
 {
  \tl_rescan:nn { } { $#1$ } &  \texttt{#1}
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I _knew_ there had to be a simple LaTeX3 answer, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What is `\tl_rescan:nn { } { $#1$ }` actually doing? I know it is some form of token list.

Comment: @azetina It's the wrapper around `\scantokens`; the first argument contains (local) assignments, for instance to set a particular category code.

Answer (score 6):

I created `\detokenizeplus` which detokenizes but removes spaces before left braces and underscores, which were the problems for your examples.  Additionally, I remove the space between consecutive macro names (but can only detect the first macro if there is space before its name).  The place where that should apply is in between `\in\Omega`.  However, because `\in` was immediately preceded by`x` and not a space, my logic can't catch that case.  So for this MWE, I made the argument `x \in\Omega` to test that I could trap consecutive macros.

The logic here is that `\getargsC` breaks up the input into space separated arguments (`\argi`, `\argii`, `\argiii`, etc.) which can be exploited to determine whether to add back a space or not when regurgitating the arguments sequentially.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{readarray}
\newcommand\showcase[1]{{\ttfamily\detokenizeplus{#1}} & $#1$}
\def\firstchar#1#2|{#1}
% catcode=12 BACKSLASH
\edef\tbs{\detokenize{\X}}
\edef\tbs{\expandafter\firstchar\tbs|}
% catcode=12 LEFT BRACE
\edef\tlb{\detokenize{{}}}
\edef\tlb{\expandafter\firstchar\tlb|}
% catcode=12 UNDERSCORE
\edef\tus{\detokenize{_}}
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand\detokenizeplus[1]{%
  \def\temparg{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \getargsC{\temparg}%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \def\prevmacro{F}%
  \whiledo{\value{index} < \narg}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
%   DETERMINE IF A MACRO; REMOVE SPACE BETWEEN CONSECUTIVE MACROS
    \isnextbyte[q]{\tbs}{\csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname}%
    \if T\theresult%
      \if T\prevmacro\unskip\else\fi%
      \def\prevmacro{T}%
    \else%
      \def\prevmacro{F}%
   \fi%
%   REMOVE SPACES BEFORE LEFT BRACE
    \isnextbyte[q]{\tlb}{\csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname}%
    \if T\theresult\unskip\else\fi%
%   REMOVE SPACES BEFORE UNDERSCORES
    \isnextbyte[q]{\tus}{\csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname}%
    \if T\theresult\unskip\else\fi%
    \csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname~%
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
\showcase{x^{y}}      & \showcase{\hat{x}, \bar{x}} \\
\showcase{x_{y}}      & \showcase{f\colon X \to Y} \\
\showcase{x'}         & \showcase{\sqrt{x+2}} \\
\showcase{x''_{2}}    & \showcase{2 < x \leq 4} \\
\showcase{A^{1}_{2}}  & \showcase{\frac{a+b}{c+d}} \\
\showcase{3\pi/4}     & \showcase{\int_{0}^{1} x^{2} \,dx} \\
\showcase{x \in\Omega} & \showcase{A \cup B \subseteq C \cap D}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use \prime instead of '