# Automatically show verbatim content of a custom environment

Tags: environments, verbatim

I've defined an environment with `\newenvironment`, which I am mainly using for `tikz` diagrams. I have it set to dynamically change the margins, vertically and horizontally center the diagrams, and put each diagram on its own page by calling `\clearpage` and the end of the environment. That all works well.

My question is how can I output the verbatim contents of the environment automatically at the end of the environment? Ideally after the `tikz` diagram is finished, I'd like to put the markup that generates that diagram on a new page. So if you were to print it double-sided, you'd have the diagram on one side, and the markup on the other.

I am not sure if this is possible. Here is what I currently have defining the environment. It's working well currently—although please let me know if I am doing something incorrectly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{myenv}[2]
    {
        \newgeometry{top=#1in, bottom=#1in, left=#2in, right=#2in}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \begin{center}
    }
    {
        \end{center}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \clearpage
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Something here that will print the content of the environment
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \restoregeometry
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{myenv}{1.75}{2}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[ultra thick] (-1, 0) -- (1, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{sentencediagram}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you want to look at `tcolorbox`

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it