# Use verbatim inside \newcommand

Tags: verbatim

Probably this was already answered. But I did not find it. How can I use verbatim inside `\newcommand{}` or `\begin{environment}...\end{environment}`. In my MWE, the last two lines produce errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\FIXME}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\FIXMA}[1]{\verb+#1+}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \verb+test test test+ \\
    \FIXME{test test test}
    \FIXME{\verb+test test test+}
    \FIXMA{test test test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use `\verb` in the argument to another command. But do you *really* need `\verb`?

Comment: can't you just use `\texttt{#1}` ?

Comment: I want an environment to not expand if I use commands inside, that is why I thought about verbatim.

Comment: `\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}` probably does the right thing if you are using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: It almost works. I just notice, e.g., if I use `\FIXME{bla \text{AAA} bla}` it gives an extra space `\text<space>{AAA}` which is not desirable.

Comment: @cacamailg that's life.

Comment: @cacamailg you can't have real verbatim and use matching `{}` as the argument delimiter as `{}` are not special in verbatim, that is why for `\verb` the user has to specify a characer that does not appar and use `\verb^xxx^ or` whatever.

Comment: I seem to recall the extra space with `\detokenize` is discussed in this question/answers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it.  Now whether you can directly employ egreg's answer or use my `\detokenizeplus`, it remains to be seen.

Comment: To wit, the relevant portion of egreg's answer would seem to be `\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\showcase}{v}
 {
  \texttt{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: Also, depending on what you seek, my `verbatimbox` package may be useful.  The `verbbox` environment saves `verbatim` content into a LaTeX box, which can be recalled, either on the command line, or inside a macro with `\theverbbox`.

Comment: Here is a `verbatimbox` example.  Let me know if it is relevant.  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\newcommand{\FIXME}[1]{$>>>$#1$<<<$}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    $>>>$\verb+test test test+$<<<$ \\
    \FIXME{test test test}\\
    \begin{verbbox}test test test\end{verbbox}
    \FIXME{\theverbbox}\\
\end{document}`

Comment: Can you post an answer based on your comments?

Comment: I have provided an answer based on my many comments.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that came to mind, when reading this question.

**POSSIBILITY 1)** `\detokenize`

David suggested this in a comment.  The OP responded that he/she was unhappy with the space that `\detokenize` automatically introduces after macro names.  That reminded me of this question, [Print small TeX code verbatim and render it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it), which provided two answers.  Egreg's accepted answer used an `\ExplSyntaxOn` approach (`xparse` package) in which

```
\usepackage{xparse} 
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\NewDocumentCommand{\showcase}{v} { \texttt{#1} } 
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

provides a verbatim macro.  My timid attempt to incorporate this inside of another macro was unsuccessful, but I am unversed at `\ExplsyntaxOn` to know whether egreg's approach could be adapted for the needs of the OP.

The other answer at that question was my own, in which I introduced `\detokenizeplus`, to trap the annoying spaces and try to eliminate them.  While I could make it work for that particular question, the approach was not bulletproof, as I noted in the answer.  Nonetheless, there is the chance to employ `\detokenizeplus` within another macro to get the benefits of the `\detokenize` approach, but without the annoying spaces.

**POSSIBILITY 2:** `verbatimbox`

My `verbatimbox` package might also have so application here, though it is hard to tell, based on the limited example provided by the OP.  What that package's `verbbox` environment does is to allow `verbatim` content to be saved inside a LaTeX box, to be later regurgitated with `\theverbbox` (note there is also a `myverbbox` environment that allows a unique name of the box to be specified).

So, while the `verbatim` content cannot be specified inside of a macro with this approach, previously specified `verbatim` content can be presented (inline) inside of the macro.  Here is an example of how that is done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\newcommand{\FIXME}[1]{$>>>$#1$<<<$}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    $>>>$\verb+test test test+$<<<$ \\
    \FIXME{test test test}\\
    \begin{verbbox}test test test\end{verbbox}
    \FIXME{\theverbbox}\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. If you *really* need verbatim material, you can use `\lstinline` from the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\newcommand{\FIXME}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\FIXMD}{\lstinline}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \FIXME{test \lstinline!test! test}\\
    \FIXMD!test \text{AAA} test!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that `\FIXMD` is really redundant but, as I said, it's not clear to me what the intended really use for the commands should be.