# How use fancyvrb to show both result and verbatim text?

Tags: macros, verbatim, fancyvrb

The documentation for `fancyvrb` claims: "you can build example environments (showing both result and verbatim text)...."

How?

For example, how should commands from `fancyvrb` be used to construct a command such as `\showboth`, shown in the "toy example" below, so that the output is what is shown as "desired" rather than the "actual" output I get?

**Toy example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand{\showboth}[1]{{#1} --- \protect\Verb!#1!}

\newcommand{\doit}[1]{also {#1}}

\begin{document}

Actual output: \quad \showboth{\doit{this}}

\bigskip

Desired output: \quad \doit{this} --- \verb!\doit{this}!

\end{document}
```

[image: How show result of command and its verbatim text]

**Actual application**

In the actual application, I need such a command \showboth that can be used with an argument that comes from the argument passed by a surrounding command.

The purpose of this is to allow me to experiment systematically with various kinds of styling in my document design. For example, I want to see readily which of various styles I prefer for cross-referencing theorems and sections, as in the following source.

In that source, the package `showboth` that's loaded consists simply of the code in the answer by @Ulrich Diez.

What I'd like is a 1-argument macro, whose argument is a label (`thm:big`, e.g.), that produces the kind of complete `itemize` environment shown (whose individual items in turn just call `\showboth` with the various referencing commands, with those referencing commands in turn taking that label as their own argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{suffix}

\usepackage{showboth} % code from Ulrich Diez's answer

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% Tefererencing macros:

\newcommand{\thmref}[1]{\nameref*{#1} (\cref{#1})}

\newcommand{\thmnameref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\nameref{#1}}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\thmnameref*[1]{\nameref*{#1}}

\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\cref{#1}} \nameref*{#1}}

\newcommand*{\unitref}[1]{\cref{#1} (\nameref*{#1})}
\newcommand*{\unitnameref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\cref{#1}} (\nameref*{#1})}

% Thorerem styles

\swapnumbers

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\bfseries,
notefont=\bfseries, 
headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape,
]{thmstyle}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\bfseries,
notefont=\bfseries, notebraces={}{},
headformat=\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape,
]{namedthmstyle}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{thmstyle}% default
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\theoremstyle{namedthmstyle}
\declaretheorem[style=namedthmstyle, name=Theorem,title = {},numberlike=theorem]{namedtheorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Stuff}\label{sec:stuff}

\begin{theorem}[refname=Theorem,name=Preliminary Result]\label{thm:prelim}
Notice this!
\end{theorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[name=The Big Theorem]\label{thm:big}
Very important!
\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:another}
Another big result.
\end{theorem}

\begin{itemize}
\item  \showboth!\thmref{thm:big}! 
\item \showboth!\thmnameref{thm:big}! 
\item \showboth!\thmnameref*{thm:big}!
\item \showboth!\fullref{thm:big}! % LITTLE USE!
\item \showboth!\nameref{thm:big} \cref{thm:big}!
\item \showboth!\nameref*{thm:big} \cref{thm:big}! 
\item \showboth!\cref{thm:big}! 
\item \showboth!\cref*{thm:big}!
\end{itemize}

\smallskip

\begin{itemize}
\item  \showboth!\thmref{thm:prelim}! 
\item \showboth!\thmnameref{thm:prelim}! 
\item \showboth!\thmnameref*{thm:prelim}!
\item \showboth!\fullref{thm:prelim}! % LITTLE USE!
\item \showboth!\nameref{thm:prelim} \cref{thm:prelim}!
\item \showboth!\nameref*{thm:prelim} \cref{thm:prelim}! 
\item \showboth!\cref{thm:prelim}! 
\item \showboth!\cref*{thm:prelim}!
\end{itemize}

\smallskip

\begin{itemize}
\item  \showboth!\thmref{thm:another}! 
\item \showboth!\thmnameref{thm:another}! 
\item \showboth!\thmnameref*{thm:another}!
\item \showboth!\fullref{thm:another}! % LITTLE USE!
\item \showboth!\nameref{thm:another} \cref{thm:another}!
\item \showboth!\nameref*{thm:another} \cref{thm:another}! 
\item \showboth!\cref{thm:another}! 
\item \showboth!\cref*{thm:another}!
\end{itemize}

\smallskip

\begin{itemize}
\item \showboth!\unitnameref{sec:stuff}!
\item \showboth!\unitref{sec:stuff}!
\item  \showboth!\thmref{sec:stuff}! 
\item \showboth!\thmnameref{sec:stuff}! 
\item \showboth!\thmnameref*{sec:stuff}!
\item \showboth!\fullref{sec:stuff}! % LITTLE USE!
\item \showboth!\nameref{sec:stuff} \cref{sec:stuff}!
\item \showboth!\nameref*{sec:stuff} \cref{sec:stuff}! 
\item \showboth!\cref{sec:stuff}! 
\item \showboth!\cref*{sec:stuff}!
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it

Comment: Neither answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it does *not* do what I need: the first answer there (using `stringstrings`) gives a spurious space between `\doit` and `{this}`; both the first and second seem to treat the result of the command as math, thus typesetting `\doit{this}` as *also this*.

Comment: Too late to edit my preceding, confusing comment to correct syntax. In first line, "does *not* do" should have been "does".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me say in advance that I am not familiar at all to the fancyvrb package as by now I never used it.

**Therefore it is unknown to me whether that package already provides some infrastructure for achieving what you desire.**

Off the cuff I suggest having `\showboth` read its argument under "verbatim catcode régime" and then having `\showboth` pass that argument to another macro `\innershowboth` which in turn will pass that argument to `\scantokens`—once as is and once along with tokens for calling the `\Verb`-command.

I just wrote a macro `\UDcollectOneVerbArg` which does read arguments under "verbatim catcode régime" and then pass these arguments and the verbatim-delimiter to other macros.
I will happily use it in the example below for implementing `\showboth`.

Like the commands `\verb` (from the LaTeX-kernel) and `\Verb` (from the fancyvrb-package) the command `\showboth` needs to read its argument under "verbatim catcode régime".
Therefore like the commands `\verb` and `\Verb` the command `\showboth` does not work with arguments that are passed by other macros/that come from macro definitions where those arguments were tokenized under normal catcode régime.
Best practise for the unexperienced is to use `\showboth<verbatim-Arg>` not within macro definitions and not within macro arguments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\makeatletter
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
%%
%% (\romannumeral expansion was introduced in order to overcome the 
%% concerns and worries about improperly balanced \if..\else..\fi constructs.)
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% // Snippet written by Ulrich Diez on November 30, 2016
%
% Implement generic stuff for reading arguments "verbatim":
%
% Syntax of \UDcollectOneVerbArg
%
%   \UDcollectOneVerbArg{<^^M-replacement>}{<mandatory>}<delimiter of verbatim arg><verbatim arg><delimiter of verbatim arg>
%   yields:
%   <mandatory>{<delimiter of verbatim arg>}{<verbatim arg>}
%
%   \UDcollectOneVerbArg{<^^M-replacement>}{<mandatory>}{<verbatim arg>}
%   yields:
%   <mandatory>{}{<verbatim arg>}
%
% with each character ^^M (usually=\endline-char) in <verbatim arg>
% replaced by token-sequence <^^M-replacement>.
%
% If reading <^^M-replacement> and <mandatory> from input is necessary,
% they will be read under unchanged catcode regime.
%
% The <verbatim arg> is also mandatory.
% It will be read under verbatim-catcode-conditions.
% There must be a leading character in front of it.
% If that leading character is an opening brace, it will be
% "assumed" that the <verbatim arg> is nested into braces.
% Otherwise it will be "assumed" that the <verbatim arg> is
% delimited by that leading character---which implies a
% syntax like with the argument of \verb.
%
% Empty-lines will not be ignored.
%
% <delimiter of verbatim arg> will be read under verbatim-catcode-conditions
% if present.
%
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\UD@firstoftwo{%
  \endgroup%
  \newcommand\UDEndlreplace[2]{\romannumeral0\@UDEndlreplace{#2}#1^^M\relax{}}%
  \newcommand*\@UDEndlreplace{}%
  \long\def\@UDEndlreplace#1#2^^M#3\relax#4#5{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}%
    { #5{#4#2}}{\@UDEndlreplace{#1}#3\relax{#4#2#1}{#5}}%
  }%
}{}%
\newcommand\UDcollectOneVerbArg{\@UDOneVerbArg{\@UDcollectOneVerbArg}}%
\newcommand\@UDOneVerbArg[3]{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\{=1 %
  \catcode`\ =10 %
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup
  {\catcode`\}=2 \@@UDOneVerbArg{#1}{#2}{#3}{}}%
  {\do\{\@@UDOneVerbArg{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}%
\newcommand\@@UDOneVerbArg[4]{%
  \do\ %
  \catcode`\^^M=12 %
  \long\def\@tempb##1#4{%
    \edef\@tempb{##1}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb
    \expandafter\UDEndlreplace\expandafter{\@tempb}{#2}{\def\@tempb}%
    \expandafter#1\expandafter{\@tempb}{#3}{#4}%
  }%
  \@tempb
}%
\newcommand\@UDcollectOneVerbArg[3]{%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
  #2{#3}{#1}%
}%
% Implementation of generic stuff for reading arguments "verbatim" done.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\showboth{\UDcollectOneVerbArg{^^J}{\innershowboth}}%
\newcommand\innershowboth[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\scantokens{{#2} --- \Verb{#2}\begingroup\catcode`\X=14 X}}%<-This will raise an error as \Verb does not accept opening braces as delimiter.
  {\scantokens{{#2} --- \Verb#1#2#1\begingroup\catcode`\X=14 X}}%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\doit}[1]{also {#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\Verb|\doit{this  and that} --- \Verb!\doit{this  and that}!| yields:\medskip\\
\null\quad \doit{this  and that} --- \Verb!\doit{this  and that}!
\bigskip

\noindent\Verb|\showboth!\doit{this  and that}!| yields:\medskip\\    
\null\quad \showboth!\doit{this  and that}!
\bigskip    

\end{document}
```

Comment: I strong suspected an answer would be non-trivial, but I hardly expected it to be so complicated! I still wonder what the `fancyvrb` docs had in mind when they said, ""you can build example environments (showing both result and verbatim text)...." (I sure wish package documentation did a consistently better job of including examples and not just explicate all the principles involved.)

Comment: @murray As I wrote in my answer: I don't know much about the fancyvrb package. Therefore I don't know if an answer has to be so complicated. I did it the way I did it because I use my `\UD...`-macros all the time. Thus providing my answer was more or less a seven minute copy-paste job with minor modifications. Going through the manual and the code of the fancyvrb package would have taken me more time. **Therefore I must lay emphasis on the fact that there might be a much less complex answer in terms of macros/infrastructure provided by the fancyvrb package.**

Comment: Alas, in the actual situation, I need such a command `\showboth` that *can* be used with an argument that comes from the argument passed by a surrounding command.

Comment: @murray Perhaps with the surrounding command you can play the same game as I played when implementing `\showboth`: Take the surrounding command for a wrapper that calls `\UDcollectOneVerbArg` which in turn reads arguments verbatim and passes them to yet another macro which in turn feeds the arguments along with whatsoever other tokens to `\scantokens` for re-tokenization... **By the way: Don't hesitate to tell about the actual situation whenever asking for help.** That way help can be adjusted to the actual situation ab ovo which often saves time - eh - in the long term.

Comment: @murray Or you just try something like `...\scantokens{\showboth!<whatsoever macro argument>!\begingroup\endlinechar=-1\relax}\endgroup...`  within the definition of the surrounding command - without having TeX read things verbatimized first. But without prior verbatimization, this does double hashes (`#`) and it does also attach spaces behind control words. (`\scantokens` is like unexpanded writing to an external file and `\input`-ting that external file.) Input-characters in `^^`-notation might also not yield what you wish without prior verbatimization.