# Verbatim math inside tabular or align environment?

Tags: verbatim

Is it be possible to display a table with both typeset math expressions and verbatim renderings the corresponding input for those expressions?

For example, something like the first two lines of output shown below, but within a `tabular` or `align` environment. (The last two lines of the output give *almost* what I want, but of course lack display of `/`.)

[image: Displaying input and output of math expressions]

The source for the above is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
$X \vee Y$ \qquad \verb!X \vee Y!
\\
$X \wedge Y$ \qquad \verb!X \wedge Y!

\noindent
\begin{align*}
X \wedge Y &\qquad \texttt{X  wedge Y}
\\
X \vee Y &\qquad \texttt{X vee Y}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Of course I am aware of how to do this when just text is involved, as considered, e.g., in: [How use fancyvrb to show both result and verbatim text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341616/how-use-fancyvrb-to-show-both-result-and-verbatim-text).

**A mathemartical aside**

Somewhat confusingly, the symbol `\vee` is used in topology to denote the *wedge* sum, whereas the symbol `\wedge` is not (it's used for the smash product).

Comment: While you can get verbatim into an align, the easist would probably be to stick with tt text, as in `\texttt{X  \char92 wedge Y}`

Comment: You can do `\texttt{X \string\wedge\ Y}` and `\texttt{X \string\vee\ Y}`.

Comment: Drat, I forgot about the `\string` command!

Comment: The problem is that `align*` absorbs the text up to `\end{align*}` as the argument to a macro, so `\verb` is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write some code to format both input and output at the same time:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathandcode}[1]{%
  \mbox{$#1$} &
    \mbox{\ttfamily \detokenize{#1}}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139980/5764
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l }
  \mathandcode{X \vee Y} \\
  \mathandcode{X \wedge Y}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps the simplest yet!

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `tabular` as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}l}
X \vee Y & \verb!X \vee Y!
\\
X \wedge Y & \verb!X \wedge Y!
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This way seems a lot simpler than having to use `\string`.