# Defining a macro for showing math formula source

Tags: math-mode, macros, verbatim

I would like to typeset an introduction to MathJAX/LaTeX formulae.

For that, I introduced a macro:

```
\newcommand{\showsource}[1]{$#1$ : \verb|#1|}
```

To typeset a math formula and then show its source.

But when I use it as

```
\showsource{\frac{1}{2}}
```

XeLaTeX complains about a missing $.

How can I write such a macro correctly?

### Edit (MWE -- Manuel Kuehner)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\showsourceA}[1]{$#1$}
\newcommand{\showsourceB}[1]{verb|#1|}

\begin{document}
\showsourceA{\frac{1}{2}}
\showsourceB{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps this question will help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it

Comment: I added a MWE -- as you can see, `\showsourceA` works and `\showsourceB` (including the `verb`) doesn't.

Comment: Wouldn't \verb|#1| print #1?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes, detokenize solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Followin Steven B. Segletes' comment and his link:

[Print small TeX code verbatim and render it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it)

I created a new, working macro:

```
\newcommand{\showsource}[1]{$#1$ \quad {\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}} }
```

and it works on

```
\showsource{\frac{1}{2}}
```

[image]

(yes, the space after `\frac` is strange but I can live with it).