# Verbatim environment nesting troubles

Tags: environments, verbatim, nesting

I have troubles trying to nest  verbatim environment inside my `\newenvironment` definition one so I can include my source code faced to its result as on the most latex books printed. I can do it in a mechanical way:

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{5in}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
\makebox[0mm]{gorilla gorilla}\\
\framebox[2mm][l]{gorilla gorilla}\\
\framebox[2mm][r]{gorilla gorilla}\\
\end{minipage}}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.5in}
\begin{verbatim}
\makebox[0mm]{gorilla gorilla}\\
\framebox[2mm][l]{gorilla gorilla}\\
\framebox[2mm][r]{gorilla gorilla}\\
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}\mbox{}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

But I'm not able do it in an automatic way by means my `\newenvironment`:

```
\newenvironment{exe}[1]{\begin{minipage}{5in}
\begin{minipage}{2.5in} #1 \end{minipage}\hfill 
\begin{minipage}{2.5in}\begin{verbatim}#1\end{verbatim}\end{minipage}}
{\end{minipage}}

\newcommand{\bex}{\begin{exe}}
\newcommand{\eex}{\end{exe}}

%Inside the body:
\bex{\framebox[2mm]{gorilla gorilla}\\
\framebox[2mm][l]{gorilla gorilla}\\
\framebox[2mm][r]{gorilla gorilla}\\
}\eex
```

The macro works if I remove `\verbatim` environment from the definition...
I'm desperate. Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advanced
Best Regards!

P.S.: For any extrange reason squared brackets are missed on the `\newenvironment` definition. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrmcd.jpg)

Comment: You can't use `verbatim` as an argument to a macro/environment.  However, this question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it, may help.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, one cannot use `verbatim` as part of a macro or environment argument.

**TOTALLY REVISED ANSWER**

This revised answer meets the need espoused by the OP in that equations may be part of the showcased code, and counters and equation numbers are retained.

Instead, here I employ `\detokenize` as a faux substitute for `verbatim`.  I cleverly use `\obeyspaces` and `\obeylines` to capture layout of source code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listofitems}
{
\obeylines
\xdef\detokenizedcr{\detokenize{
}}% TO CAPTURE A DETOKENIZED CARRIAGE RETURN
\gdef\showcaseaux#1{\par\noindent%
  \xdef\tmp{\detokenize{#1}}%
  \greadlist\mycode{\tmp}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}%
  \let^^M=\space#1\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace{.04\textwidth}%
%  \fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{% UNCOMMENT THIS LINE TO SEE BOXES
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}\ttfamily
  \foreachitem\x\in\mycode{\ifnum\xcnt=1\else\\\fi\mbox{}\x}%
  \strut%
  \end{minipage}%
%  }% UNCOMMENT THIS LINE TO SEE BOXES
  \par
  \catcode`\^^M=5 %
  \catcode`\ =10 }
}
\newcommand\showcase{\obeylines\obeyspaces\showcaseaux}
\expandafter\setsepchar\expandafter{\detokenizedcr}
\begin{document}
\showcase{Here is an example of an unnumbered displayed equation:
   \[ x' + y^2 = z_{i}^2 \]}
\showcase{and here is the same equation numbered:
 \begin{equation}
   x' + y^2 = z_{i}^2
 \end{equation}}
\showcase{and here is another equation numbered:
 \begin{equation}
   z = \frac{x}{y}
 \end{equation}}
 \showcase{As you can see, the vertical alignments are good.}
Are    we
  back to
     normal    yet?

\noindent\hrulefill

Here is what happens if you don't block the showcases separately:
\showcase{Here is an example of an unnumbered displayed equation:
   \[ x' + y^2 = z_{i}^2 \]
and here is the same equation numbered:
 \begin{equation}
   x' + y^2 = z_{i}^2
 \end{equation}
and here is another equation numbered:
 \begin{equation}
   z = \frac{x}{y}
 \end{equation}
As you can see, the vertical alignments 
can get off and page-breaking will be an issue.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the following image, I uncomment two lines in the source code to display how the `\showcase` perform when blocked separately, and when not.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have to understand how it Works but it looks nice. Thanks you so much

Comment: @Sergio `\detokenize` is similar to `verbatim`, but has more limitations (no `%` allowed, braces must be balanced, does not obey lines, etc.).  In addition, it automatically inserts a space at the end of *every* macro name (in this example `\makebox` and `\framebox`).

Comment: Hi Steven, your proposal is not useful for me due to I need break lines inside and all forbidden characters availables as well. I think that a pair of minipage nested into main minipage must be the right solution as I told you most of the Latex books make it

Comment: Hi Steven I've included a pair of pictures what I need about. Do you have any solution for it?

Comment: @Sergio Your images just made the problem much more complicated.  Not only do you wish to render code on the left, but you wish to do so with all the counters and environments intact, so that, for example, equations are counted and numbered.

Comment: Yes I know,  minipage it must be the surround, is something like this just including verbatim inside:

Comment: %\newenvironment{exe}[1]{\begin{minipage}{5in}
%\begin{minipage}{2.5in} #1 \end{minipage}\hfill 
%\begin{minipage}{2.5in}\begin{verbatim}#1\end{verbatim}\end{minipage}}
%{\end{minipage}}

\newcommand{\bex}{\begin{exe}}
\newcommand{\eex}{\end{exe}}

Comment: Dear Steven, Awesome solution I'm very impressed, thanks a lot just I see another trouble, \showcase is not able to put up \captions on nested table environment, could do it as well? Thanks in advanced