# Using menukeys to typeset paths containing hyphens

Tags: punctuation, paths, menukeys

I want to use the `menukeys` package to typeset directories and filenames, but if a filename contains a hyphen, the output adds a space before the hyphen,eg

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\renewmenumacro{\directory}[bslash]{paths}
\begin{document}
Type \directory{C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d\site-lisp}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to avoid this?[image: Example output]

Comment: As this bug persists, did you send a mail to the maintainer (or ping him here)?

Comment: No, I had forgotten. Thanks for reminding me; I just sent him email.

Comment: Tobi mailed me back to say he's in the middle of his thesis and stuck for time. So I'm going to have a look myself.

Comment: Any news here ?

Comment: *Disclaimer: Currently I'm one of the two maintainers of `menukeys`.* This won't be fixed and in future versions the `bslash` syntax will most likely be dropped entirely. I've provided some reasoning at the [issue-thread on Github](https://github.com/tweh/menukeys/issues/48). Basically this can't be correctly parsed in a foolproof (and backwards compatible) manner, so there is no real point in trying, imho.

Answer (score 1):

If the separator character is `bslash` then the `menukeys` package uses `\detokenize` to parse the input. This is needed to prevent interpretation of `\` characters as starting a control sequence (e.g., `\Users\username` could be interpreted as the LaTeX command `\Users` followed by the command `\username`).

However, `\detokenize` adds a space at the end of each control sequence (see [What are the exact semantics of \detokenize?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20059/what-are-the-exact-semantics-of-detokenize) and [Detokenizing without extra spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44391/detokenizing-without-extra-spaces)). Normally this is not a problem in `menukeys`, because the space is added at the end of a 'word', where either a space is needed (for paths with spaces) or where it is discarded at the end of the current directory name when printing the separator character.

An exception is a directory name that is not a valid control sequence name, such as `\site-lisp`. Here `\detokenize` parses `\site`, adds an extra space because it is at the end of a control sequence, and continues with `-lisp`.

The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45292/ from the second related question mentioned above notes an alternative for `\detokenize`, which is the `v` argument specifier in `expl3`. Such an argument is read verbatim and converted into character codes 10 (space) and 12 (other), which means that `\` will not be interpreted as the start of a control sequence. This specifier therefore removes the need for `\detokenize`. Further processing in `menukeys`, specifically splitting the argument by the separator character with `\seq_set_split`, does not seem to be affected. Normal spaces in path names still work. Note however that I did not extensively test for any side effects.

To properly implement this modification the source code of the package should be changed (if the package maintainer approves of course). I added a comment at the existing Github issue https://github.com/tweh/menukeys/issues/48. However, as a temporary fix you can redefine the `\directory` macro in your own document, with the `v` specifier, in which the occurrences of `\detokenize` and `\unexpanded` are removed. Note that the `bslash` default value is hardcoded in the MWE below (the redefinition does not follow the `\renewmenumacro` command - but you can still provide the optional argument if necessary).

---

Update: in the Github issue the package maintainer stated that there would be too many side effects for this approach (for example that you cannot use actual macros in the path name anymore). He intends to drop support for backslash-delimited paths altogether in future releases of menukeys. So if you want to properly format this type of paths (and you don't mind about not using macros in the paths and not nesting menukeys macros) then you can use the code below.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\renewmenumacro{\directory}[bslash]{paths}
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\directory{+O{bslash}+v}%           
{%
\leavevmode
\begingroup
  \def\tw@current@color@theme
    {\csname tw@style@paths@color@theme\endcsname}%
  \@nameuse{tw@style@paths@pre}%
  \tw@mk@test@input@sep{#1}
    {%
      \edef\tw@menu@list{#2}%
      \edef\tw@mk@tempa{\@backslashchar}%
    }
    {%
      \edef\tw@menu@list{#2}%
      \edef\tw@mk@tempa{\tw@mk@trimspaces{#1}}%
    }%
  \begingroup
    \letcs{\tw@mk@tempb}{tw@parse@menu@list@directory}%
    \tw@mk@indrisloop\tw@mk@tempa\tw@menu@list\tw@mk@tempb
  \endgroup
  \@nameuse{tw@style@paths@post}%
\endgroup
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\noindent Type \directory{C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d\site-lisp}\\
Type \directory[/]{C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/site-lisp}\\
Type \directory{C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d\site-lisp}   
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]