# Extra space in menukey’s directory output with 'bslash' sep

Tags: catcodes, menukeys

A user of `menukeys` reported ([GutHub issue #48](https://github.com/tweh/menukeys/issues/48)) that there is an extra space before hyphens in a directory sequence, when the input separator is a back slash:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}
this: \directory[bslash]{c:\temp\dir-dir} (extra space before \verb|-|)

should be the same as this: \directory[/]{c:/temp/dir-dir}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve it. Any ideas here in the community?

Comment: Well the source of the problem is that TeX inserts a space after command names, and that the parser later on doesn't remove it in `\dir -dir`. But I can't tell you if it is a catoptions bug or if you are using it in a wrong way. Neither the menukeys code nor the catoptions code is really comprehensible, and catoptions has no docu. As a work-around you can give the hyphen (and the other chars affected by the same problem) locally letter catcode.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it. Seems to be not as easy to fix as I hoped …

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369361/using-menukeys-to-typeset-paths-containing-hyphens