# menukeys: inconsistent path with backslashes

Tags: menukeys

I have an (inconsistent) issue with menukeys. I don't know why it inserts spaces in the path.

Tex-file:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

% Language setting
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% MENUKEYS, für Pfade und Tasten-Symbole
\usepackage{menukeys}
\makeatletter
% --- macro for changing path sep ---
\newcommand\setnewpathsep[1]
{%
    \tw@declare@style@simple*{paths}{%
    {\ttfamily\CurrentMenuElement}%
    }[#1]{blacknwhite}
}
\setnewpathsep{\textbackslash}
\makeatother

% % % % % 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \directory[bslash]{.\3D_Some.Path\somemore\3D_More-FileNames_V2.wbpj} \\ - Why is this correct?
    \item \directory[bslash]{.\3D_Some.Path\even more\3D_More-FileNames.wbpj} \\  - Why is this correct?
    \item \directory[bslash]{.\3D_Some.Path\More\Main.wbpj} \\ - Why is there a space before the extension?
    \item \directory[bslash]{.\3D_Some.Path\More\Ma_in.wbpj} \\  - Why is there a space after Ma?
    \item \directory[bslash]{.\3D_Some.Path\More\2D_Main.wbpj} \\  - Why is this correct?
    \item \directory[bslash]{.\3D_Some.Path\More\xD_Ma_in.wbpj} \\ - Why is there a space after xD?
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: menukeys issue]

I have uploaded it to overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/zfmdmjbmwwtp
The same issue with TeXstudio...

Comment: you are getting spaces after command names so `\More`, `\ma`  but not after control symbols like `\2`

Comment: Wha..?! And how can I prevent menukeys (or LaTeX) from doing that and render my paths corretly?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the linked question. Furthermore https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/391393/4918 is related. As saids in GitHub in issue #48 this is not trivial to fix and for now – sorry – closed as “won’t fix“.