# Mintinline in Tabularx / remove space in detokenize

Tags: macros, tabularx, verbatim, minted, detokenize

I write a LaTeX manual in `memoir` class with the Minted package, TeXlive 2021 and TeXmaker.

To insert some `\mintinline` code in a Tabularx X-type column, I used this [trick](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/162) and it work. Except that it produce a "detokenized verbatim command" with spaces after detokenized command name and I want to remove them (or any other unwanted spaces). Also, I want to keep the same form that a `\mintinline` code outside a tabularx environment.

For that, I tried many many solutions ([this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it) with the apparently uneffective macro `\detokenizeplus` or [those one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44391/detokenizing-without-extra-spaces)) and none of them work (or I'm just too bad for it), inside or outside the tabularx environment. The closest solution is to use the [tokcycle package](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/generic/tokcycle/tokcycle-examples.pdf) and his macro `\altdetokenize`, which, at least, work outside the tabularx environment.

To proceed, I had rewrote the definition of the `mintinline` macro, like in the following MWE (see the comments). It remove error at the compilation and I produce the wanted `mintinline` result, but I don't understand why it keep those unwanted spaces (I suppose that it's beyond my LaTeX skills) and I need your help :

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tokcycle}

\newif\ifmacro
\newcommand\altdetokenize[1]{\begingroup\stripgroupingtrue\macrofalse
  \stripimplicitgroupingcase{-1}%
  \tokcycle
    {\ifmacro\def\tmp{##1}\ifcat\tmp A\else\unskip\allowbreak\fi\macrofalse\fi
     \detokenize{##1}\ifx##1\bgroup\unskip\fi\ifx##1\egroup\unskip\fi}
    {\ifmacro\unskip\macrofalse\fi\{\processtoks{##1}\ifmacro\unskip\fi\}\allowbreak}
    {\tctestifx{\\##1}{\\}{\ifmacro\unskip\allowbreak\fi
     \allowbreak\detokenize{##1}\macrotrue}}
    {\hspace{0pt plus 3em minus .3ex}}
    {#1}%
  \unskip
\endgroup}

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd{\mintinline}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \setboolean{minted@isinline}{true}%
  \minted@configlang{#2}%
  \setkeys{minted@opt@cmd}{#1}%
  \minted@fvset
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\{=1
  \catcode`\}=2
  \catcode`\^^I=\active
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup
    {\minted@inline@iii}%
    {\catcode`\{=12\catcode`\}=12
      \minted@inline@i}}
\def\minted@inline@i#1{%
  \endgroup
  \def\minted@inline@ii##1#1{%
    \minted@inline@iii{##1}}%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  \catcode`\^^I=\active
  \minted@inline@ii}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{minted@draft}}%
  {\renewcommand{\minted@inline@iii}[1]{%
    \endgroup
    \begingroup
    \minted@defwhitespace@retok
    \everyeof{\noexpand}%
    \endlinechar-1\relax
    \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
    \catcode`\ =\active
    \catcode`\^^I=\active
    \xdef\minted@tmp{\scantokens{#1}}%
    \endgroup
    \let\FV@Line\minted@tmp
    \def\FV@SV@minted@tmp{%
      \FV@Gobble
      \expandafter\FV@ProcessLine\expandafter{\FV@Line}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@get@opt{breaklines}{false}}{true}}%
     {\let\FV@BeginVBox\relax
      \let\FV@EndVBox\relax
      \def\FV@BProcessLine##1{\FancyVerbFormatLine{##1}}%
      \BUseVerbatim{minted@tmp}}%
     {\BUseVerbatim{minted@tmp}}%
    \endgroup}}%
  {\renewcommand{\minted@inline@iii}[1]{%
    \endgroup
    \minted@writecmdcode{#1}%
    \RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}%
    \setcounter{minted@FancyVerbLineTemp}{\value{FancyVerbLine}}%
    \ifx\@footnotetext\TX@trial@ftn% <===== test if the macro is inside tabularx environment
    \altdetokenize{\minted@pygmentize{\minted@lang}}% <===== detokenize the token to avoid error (and supposed without unwanted space but it won't work)
    \else
    \minted@pygmentize{\minted@lang}% <===== normal behavior if outside of 
    \fi
    \setcounter{FancyVerbLine}{\value{minted@FancyVerbLineTemp}}%
    \endgroup}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text with \mintinline{latex}{\inlinecode\without\space\after\command}.\\


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X }
\toprule
 \mintinline{latex}{\inlinecode\without\space\after\command}    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

If you can show me a elegant solution, I will be grateful !

Comment: I cannot help because I do not use `minted`.  However, I can say that `tokcycle` and thus `\altdetokenize` work upon the *unexpanded* tokens of their input stream/argument.  Thus, when yu say `\altdetokenize{\minted@pygmentize{\minted@lang}}`, it is literally those tokens being detokenized, not what they later expand to.