# detokenize produces an undesired space after command sequence

Tags: macros, detokenize

I made a simple macro called `\cmd{}` which detokenizes the input. I would like to print the contents exactly as shown, and it works as I desire, except that it seems to produce a space between an inputted command sequence and the curly braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\cmd{\test{}}
\end{document}
```

results in `\test {}`

[image]

Edit: I would like a verbatim-like macro called `\cmd{}` that does the following:

`\cmd{\test{}}` → `\test{}`

Edit: I did try the solutions posed in [Detokenizing without extra spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44391/detokenizing-without-extra-spaces), but have had no luck. I am using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: It looks to me like you actually want `\verb`, but this sounds like an XY problem: what *exactly*  are you after?

Comment: That is what `\detokenize` does.  If your argument is a single control sequence, `\string` can produce it without the space.  What is your actual use case?

Comment: Are you aware of the posting [Detokenizing without extra spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44391/5001)

Comment: @Mico  did not see that post--perhaps this should be flagged as duplicate.

Comment: `\detokenize` is like writing tokens unexpanded to an external file and then inputting the external file under a category code régime where the space character has category code 10 (space) and all other characters have category code 12(other) and `\endlinechar` has a negative value. `\newlinechar` is obeyed with the writing-part. When writing a control word token, TeX automatically appends a space character. Another peculiarity of TeX's way of writing tokens is: When writing an explicit hash of category 6(parameter) that gets doubled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the paramater `\test{}` is scanned then it is tokenized to three tokens: `\test`, `{` and `}`. The `\detokenize` primitive always prints the token which is a control sequence separated by a space, so, it prints `\test {}`.

If you want to keep the spacing like it is written in the parameter, you must to read it in verbatim mode. It means that the `{` and `}` must be read asn normal characters in the text `\test{}`. But the parameter is separeted by `{` and `}` and they cannot be normal characters in this case. This is nearly impossible to read internal `{}` as normal characters and use `{...}` around the parameter. So, I suggest to use different parentheses for parameter separators:

```
\def\cmd{\bgroup\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12}\dospecials \cmdA}
\def\cmdA[#1]{\egroup{\tt#1}}

\cmd[\test{}]
```

Another approach is to set only `\` and   as normal characters, read the parameter (with balanced braces) and do `\detokenize` after it:

```
\def\cmd{\bgroup\catcode`\\=12 \catcode`\ =12 \cmdA}
\def\cmdA#1{\egroup{\tt\detokenize{#1}}}

second test: \cmd{\test{}}
```