# Empty argument to \string

Tags: tex-core

What is the result from `\string{}` and why can't we use it in place of `\detokenize` to check if a macro argument is empty as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20064/52230)?

Comment: `\string` stringifies the next token, in that case `{`, and the result is an unbalanced closing brace.

Comment: String doesn't take *one argument* but *one token*. So `\string{}` is converted to `\string{` (that prints the `{`) and a closing brace `}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the TeXbook, page 213:

> • `\string`⟨token⟩. TeX first reads the ⟨token⟩ without expansion. If a control sequence token appears, its `\string` expansion consists of the control sequence name (including `\escapechar` as an escape character, if the control sequence isn’t simply an active character). Otherwise the ⟨token⟩ is a character token, and its character code is retained as the expanded result.

Thus the argument to `\string` ***can't*** be included in braces: with

```
\string{}
```

the `{` is “stringified”, returning a `{`<sub>12</sub> character token and the following `}` remains untouched.

On the contrary, `\detokenize` takes as argument a ⟨general text⟩. Here's the excerpt from the manual of ε-TeX

> • `\detokenize`⟨general text⟩.
>   The expansion is a list of character tokens representing the token list ⟨balanced text⟩. As with the lists of character tokens produced by TeX’s `\the` and ε-TeX’s `\readline`, these tokens have category 12 (‘other’), except that the character code 32 gets category 10 (‘space’).

So `\detokenize` ***must*** be followed by a `{` (after a possible ⟨filler⟩) and its argument is whatever follows until the matching ⟨right brace⟩ (that is an *explicit* character token with category code 2). As with all instances of ⟨general text⟩, TeX will expand tokens in order to find `{`.