# \ifx comparing empty arguments not working?

Tags: macros

I have a problem with testing whether an argument is empty or not. The following sample code should return "correct" but does not.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ifxnotworking}[1]{
\if #1{}
    correct 
\else
    false
\fi}

\begin{document}
\ifxnotworking{}
\end{document}
```

Comparing `{}{}` or with `\empty` has the same result. This only occurs with empty strings, as far as I know.
Does anyone know why and what would be a proper Solution?

Answer (score 3):

The most robust way of checking for an empty argument is `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` as far as I know (most likely egreg shows up and gives a way more detailed answer).

So a robust command to check for emptiness would be:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myifempty}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo%
  \else%
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\myifempty{foo}{empty}{not empty}\\% yields "not empty"
\myifempty{}{empty}{not empty}% yields "empty"
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20064/4427

Comment: the old-timers folklore says `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` was put forward by @HeikoOberdiek, but maybe he was not first (e-TeX was slowly digested by first-timers TeX macro-ers)

Comment: @egreg so I was right, there is a way more detailed answer you provided :)

Answer (score 3):

There are better ways to do that, but let me explain what's going wrong.

When you call `\ifxnotworking{}`, TeX will replace `#1` with nothing (the braces are stripped off an undelimited argument), so the input stream will have

```
•\if {}•correct•\else false•\fi
```

(where `•` represents a space token). Now `\if` compares the following unexpandable two tokens (after having performed full expansion until finding two of them, but here there's no expandable token): the two unexpandable tokens are `{` and `}` which have different character code, so the test returns false.

Note that `\if` compares *character codes*.