# Storing environment arguments

Tags: macros, environments

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\baz}{}
\newenvironment{foo}[1]{#1}{\makeatletter\g@addto@macro\baz{#1}\makeatother}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}{bar}
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

The example does not work. What I am aiming to achieve is concatenating all parameters used with `foo`, so I can output them at the end of the document. What is the correct approach for that?

Comment: You cannot access the arguments from within the second body of `\newenvironment`.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to this problem: you can't use `\makeatletter` etc. inside command arguments because they are parsed when they are read, not when they are executed.

Comment: unlike `\newenvironment`, with `\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{m}{}{#1}` the end-code argument can refer to the arguments `#1`, `#2`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be easier to store the parameters at the start of the environment, rather than at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\baz}{}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{foo}[1]{\g@addto@macro\baz{#1}}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}{kidney}
\end{foo}
\begin{foo}{spleen}
\end{foo}
\begin{foo}{liver}
\end{foo}

\baz
\end{document}
```

If you need to do it at the end, you might find the solutions to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17036/why-cant-the-end-code-of-an-environment-contain-an-argument) useful.

Comment: I can make it work that way. The original problem required I add some information calculated at the end of the environment as well. I have now added the argument information at the beginning, and the calculated information at the end of the environment. Thanks.