# Converting command to result

Tags: expansion, primitives

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}{}
\newcommand{\currentbar}{\thebar}

\newcounter{bar}
\setcounter{bar}{0}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{baz}{\addtocounter{bar}{1}}{\g@addto@macro\foo{\currentbar}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{baz}
\end{baz}

\begin{baz}
\end{baz}

\foo
\end{document}
```

I have a command named `\foo`, a counter named `bar` and an enviroment `baz`. I would like `\foo` to store the state of the counter `bar` at each end environment `baz`.

At the end of the first `baz`, `bar` equals `1`, so `1` should be written to `\foo`. At the end of the second `baz`, `bar` equals `2` so `\foo` should be `12` (2 is concantenated to the already existing `1`).

As is, the `\foo` is most likely actually `\currentbar\currentbar`, and that outputs `22` when called at the end of the document.

How could I "expand" the `\currentbar` to `1` and `2` so that `\foo` would be `12` at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand `\currentbar` at the moment of adding it to `\foo`.

The simplest way is to use `\xappto` from the **etoolbox** package: instead of `\g@addto@macro\foo{\currentbar}`, say

```
\xappto\foo{\currentbar}
```

Of course `\usepackage{etoolbox}` in the preamble is needed.

Comment: You're a lifesaver, egreg :). Something I noticed; apparently `\\` must be appended with `\gappto` if one wants to create tabular data that way.

Comment: @ipavlic: `\gappto` is exactly the same as `\g@addto@macro` and the `g` stands for "global": environments form a group, so definitions inside them are lost when they are closed, unless the definition is global. If you try `texdef -t latex g@addto@macro` you'll see that this macro is defined with `\xdef` (global expanded definition).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I tried to write ` \\ `, but it was misformatted.

Comment: @ipavlic Such a command should not be expanded: add `\noexpand` in front of it. This neutralizes the expandability during an `\edef` or `\xdef`.